# One page responsive website with select menu that can move to anchor points

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, menu, html-select

I've been working on a one page responsive website with a fixed header that stays at the top and it basically scrolls to different points depending on what you navigation button you click (it just a simple UL menu) now, when browser shrinks to a certain size I want it to switch to a select menu that you can just tap to scroll to the part of the page.

I can do all this easily I just can't get it to scroll to them through anchors.

I know that the way you do this is through js as I've been doing some reading on others with similar problems but the replies seem to be posted for some one who has a bit of knowledge in js. Which brings me to the problem, I'm pretty horrible with js :(. So would anyone be able to tell me what i need to do to make a select menu, scroll to an anchor on a page with js.

this is what I already have.

```
        <ul id="nav">
                <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
            </ul>

            <select> 
                <option value="" selected="selected">Navigation</option> 
                <option value="#home">Home</option> 
                <option value="#about">About</option> 
                <option value="#portfolio">Portfolio</option> 
                <option value="#services">Services</option>
            </select>
```

if it helps at all, I'm using the skeleton boilerplate for my site.

Thanks in advance guys :)

(and I'm not sure I've seen different people saying the select menu needs to be in form tags and some saying it doesn't so if you could clarify that, it would be awesome :) )

Comment: Have you tried something for this.

Comment: There are many tutorials on the net that teach you how to design a responsive web site. If you want a responsive design, the good approach is to start with minimum resolution first and then build it up to max.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm understanding your problem right. The idea of an achor with a "#something" href is that when clicked it adds "#something" to your URL, called a [fragment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). This causes the browser to try and bring the element with id "something" to the top of the screen.

I'm sorry if this is not your problem - if it's not please clarify.

Comment: alright take http://www.wampserver.com/en/ for an example right. when you click its navigation menu it scrolls down to where that #something is on the page, im basically trying to do that with a select menu that is only visible at mobile phone size, just for usability. the ONLY thing i need is to figure out how i can get a select menu to scroll to the #something. iv done research and people said you cant use anchors in a select menu unless you use some jquery to help it along, i dont know jquery very well so im looking for some one to explain it in dumbed down terms for me how to do this.

Comment: @user2142866 its just a suggestion, there are already questions like this and you should search in a correct way. try `animate html body on click`.

Comment: @Jai now im confused, iv looked for like a good hour before posting this question, all i need is a select menu to be able to scroll to a point on a page like how you would do with anchors, iv seen other peoples answers to similiar problems involving something with jquery should i even be bothering with this or just change it to normal drop down menu instead of a select menu?

Comment: You can try with `.change()` event of jQuery and animate the body to the specific id. Thats it.

Comment: I think I know what you mean now - you need to create a function scrollElement, which would do something like `x = document.getElementById("selectElement");
 spot = x.selectedIndex;
 thing = x.options[spot].text;

 location.hash = thing;` and set the onchange attribute of the select element to scrollElement. This accomplishes the same thing as clicking an anchor.